# Kubernetes can't pull docker image from AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-ecr

we are a microservice architecture on kubernetes. Since a simple kernel update. Our testing environment is unable to pull the docker images from the AWS ECR repository. We are running it on a EC2 server.

This is my error message:

> Failed to pull image
>   "595264310722.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/com.my-company.gateway:1.0.2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unauthorized: authentication required.

All the rules in the IAM look fine. Do you guys have any ideas where to look?

Best regards

Comment: Please add the IAM policy.

Comment: And also which kubernetes version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been found. We had a version mismatch between our client and our server version.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what fixed the issue, I am kind of facing the same issue